# .aspx pages redirected but not .html

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

We switched our website from a custom .NET solution to a Wordpress site. As a result, I have needed to write a couple specific URL Rewrite rules in IIS to 301 redirect old urls to their equivalent pages in the Wordpress site. Considering the following 2 rules, rule 1 will match and redirect properly. However, rule 2 won't. My question is, why doesn't the rule 2 work? The only difference seems to be .html vice .aspx.

### Rule 1

**Pattern:**

```
our-company/our-staff.aspx
```

**URL:**

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/our-company/our-staff.aspx
```

### Rule 2

**Pattern**

```
labs/some-file.html
```

**URL:**

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/labs/some-file.html
```

Comment: Are you using some sort of managed rewrite module?  Perhaps `*.html` is handled as a static file.  Please add information about your server, pipeline mode, which rewrite module you use, etc.

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 on IIS 7.5 using Integrated pipeline mode.

Comment: Hmm, seems like it should work then.  Maybe paste in your `<rewrite>` section from `web.config`?

Comment: As per @MikeChristensen's comment above, we would need to see your rewrite rules.

Comment: So here's something weird. I took off the .html part and the rule worked. I was just going to leave that way as a workaround but curiosity got me, so I went back to the rule and added the .html back in and it is now working that way too. Rewriter module bug perhaps?

Comment: Maybe for some reason, IIS didn't detect the change in web.config the first time and didn't recycle the app.